# How can I do name resolution on Mavericks?

Tags: networking, dns, avahi

I would like to map a IP addresses in my local network to a name of my choice.
The network is being used by others, this name should only be available when used by my machine.
I have been looking for a mac tool for this purpose, like Avahi on other linux distributions.

Is there a tool or a simple command for this purpose?

Comment: Just edit your HOSTS file.

Comment: Could you clarify whether you want the name to be seen only by your computer; or owned by your computer but resolvable from all LAN devices?

Answer (score 1):

That's what the hosts file is for. Launch Terminal, type the following command, and press return. As with all sudo commands, you’ll need to also enter your admin password to execute it:

```
sudo nano /private/etc/hosts
```

When you’re done making changes, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> to exit the editor, <kbd>Y</kbd> to save, and Return to overwrite the existing hosts file.

Flush your DNS cache in case the changes are not picked up right away, on Mavericks, do it like this:

```
dscacheutil -flushcache; sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```